# Is CoreBluetooth framework compatible with BLE 5.0 devices(Peripherals)?

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I don't have much idea about iOT devices right now. I did some implementation in swift with CoreBluetooth framework. The bluetooth peripheral I am currently trying to use is HC-05 Bluetooth module used with Arduino.

But ultimately, I need to have a communication with Bluetooth 5.0 peripherals from iOS devices.

Is it supported/possible in CoreBluetooth? 
Also Please help me to get a Bluetooth 5.0 testing device which will work with Arduino.

Update - HC- 05 does not work with iOS - [Refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50443456/connecting-hc-05-with-iphone-se-iosv11-0)

Comment: This is an older answer from the beginning of the year, but it appears to still hold true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499262/using-bluetooth-5-on-iphone

Answer (score 2):

As CodeBender mentioned, there is no support for Bluetooth 5 yet. However, Apple is adding support for Bluetooth 5 in the next release of iOS (iOS 13). The main Bluetooth 5 features that will be supported are:-

- 2MPHY support
- Advertising Extensions
- Extended Scanning and Connection

You can find more information about this here:-

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/901

If you want a device for testing a Bluetooth 5 device, there are a few Android devices that already have Bluetooth 5 features. Samsung Galaxy S8 for example has 2MPHY support, and I believe S9 and S10 have both 2MPHY and CODED PHY support. You can use nRF Connect app on Android and checking "**Device Information**".

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well "Bluetooth 5.0 peripherals" doesn't say much. Bluetooth is a standard containing many technologies and in every version a bunch of new *optional* features and technologies are added, but seldom many *required* features. That said, most 4.0 BLE peripherals would probably pass certification for Bluetooth 5.1 without any hardware or firmware change.

If you mean a Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral advertising using "Legacy Advertising" (the one introduced in 4.0) and not "Extended Advertising", then yes, Core Bluetooth supports it. Which Bluetooth version the peripheral is certified for isn't relevant; only which features it uses.